# AUTOSYS job failing immediately

Tags: autosys

Autosys returns and error code 121, even though the job hosted on the Autosys server have executed successfully. 
i just replicated the existing bash new name and other items correctly.

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: What have you tried? [Error 121 is "Cannot open std_in_file (unix error)](http://www.scribd.com/doc/76701942/Autosys-Ps-Return-Codes-Std)"

Comment: is it due to code issue or from autosys side ?

Comment: i have no clue where to look for this issue

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the exit code? In the job definition you might have different success value that is different from the executed command exit value.

Comment: How do i check this?>